# Execute the line pipping its STDOUT to a new tab

Tags: key-bindings

I have a lot of plaintext documentation of many different programming languages I like to browse with vim. My documents look like

```
w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/events.html
w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html
w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/net.html
```

So to just yank paste them in the terminal to get the information.
But I end up pipping it to a text document that I end up opening with vim

So to simplify this I learnt either to

```
:%!w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html
```

For what I have a shortcut with `<f6>` in my `~/.vimrc`

```
nmap <F6> :exec '!'.getline('.')
```

It just takes `<f6>` and `<Enter>` to spawn a temporary shell with that website

But I wanted it to be opened in a new tab, for that I learnt that the command to input in vim is

```
:tab term w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html
```

But unfortunately using this `<f6>` and `<Enter>` on this line will still be spawning a new shell.

Do you know how to change that `<f6>` keybinding to adapt it to this `:tab term` functionality?

Comment: This is irrelevant to your question, but consider using `readability-cli` for a much better output (`readable 'https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html' | w3m -dump -T text/html`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's brake down what you want to do:

1. open a new tab
2. get the output from a command
3. put that output into the newly opened tab

So in Vim commands, this would be:

1. `:tabnew`
2. `:call system('command')`
3. `:call append(previous output)`

So now, let put this all together into a "single" command, that can be mapped. To concatenate several commands at once, we can use the `|` command:

```
:tabnew |:call systemlist('w3m -dump http...')->append(0)
```

We can use the method syntax to chain several Vim Script functions to work on the resulting output. It's a bit like piping in the shell from one command to the next.

Now we need to translate this into a mappable sequence. That means to explicitly add `<cr>` in front of the `|` to make it clear Vim has to *hit Enter*. Also we need to translate the `|` into `<Bar>` or otherwise this would terminate the mapping and execute the `next` command right when defining the mapping instead of when the mapping is executed.

So this would turn the sequence into:

```
nnoremap <f6> :nnoremap <f6> :tabnew <CR><bar>:call systemlist('w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html')->append(0)<cr>
```

There are perhaps a few minor improvements we can add:

1. mark the buffer as a `nofile` buffer, so that vim allows to easily throw away this without complaining about changes
2. give the buffer a meaning fule name
3. move the cursor to the top of the buffer

The first can be achieved by setting the *'buftype'* option, e.g. `:set buftype=nofile`.
The second by using `tabnew <filename>`
And the third, by executing the normal mode command `gg` at the end. This would make our mapping:

```
:nnoremap <f6> :tabnew +set\ buftype=nofile scratch.txt<CR><bar>:call systemlist('w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html')->append(0)<cr><bar>gg
```

Comment: It is not working, I am starting step by step. First of all if I execute this manually on vim's console `:tabnew |:call systemlist('w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html')->append(0)` this will error to `E488: Trailing characters`

Comment: Also the final goal is to be able to in a text document with lines made up of links such as `https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/net.html` be able to place the cursor on top of them an press a keybinding which will execute that certain command (of opening a new tab with the STDOUT of `w3m -dump <VIM-LINE>` ) This command does execute the command that is on the line `nmap <F6> :exec '!'.getline('.')` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883917/execute-current-line-in-bash-from-vim)

Comment: I am not sure where the E488 comes from. Does the calling the systemlist command throw that error? What Vim version and what is your shell?

Comment: For older versions of vim which do not support the method syntax (`->`), this will cause that E488 error. In that case the mapping can be rewritten like this: `:nnoremap <f6> :tabnew +set\ buftype=nofile scratch.txt<CR><bar>:call append(0, systemlist('w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html'))<cr><bar>gg`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get the problem right, but with the following mapping I get result in the new tabpage by pressing `<F6>`:

```
nnoremap <F6> :tab term w3m -dump https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html<CR>
```

without spawning a new shell.